# Combinatorial sense of number of combinations

Tags: combinatorics, summation, combinations

I have to prove that sum of all combinations $\left(^n_0\right) + \left(^n_1\right)+\left(^n_2\right)+...+\left(^n_n\right) = 2^n$, using combinatorial sense of number of combinations. So, i can't abuse the binomial theorem here. But what is the combinatorial sense of combinations?

I understand this sense as follows: $\left(^n_k\right)$ is the amount of ways how we can choose $k$ distinct elements from collection of $n$ distinct elements. So, then $\left(^n_0\right)$ is the amount of ways to choose $0$ elements. We can choose $0$ elements only by choosing nothing. There is only one way to choose nothing, so $\left(^n_0\right) = 1$. Then $\left(^n_1\right) = n$, $\left(^n_2\right) = \frac{n(n - 1)}{2}$. And this is the point, where i'm getting confused. Am i doing right things here? And if so, how can i accurately calculate my sum?

Comment: Perhaps, it's best sticking to the exact combinatorial interpretation is $\binom nk$: the number of subsets with $k$ elements of a set of $n$ elements.

Comment: how many ways can you flip n coins?

Comment: @Zackkenyon Yea, $2^n$. It is either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: how many ways can you flip n coins such that k of them are heads?

Comment: @Zackkenyon Since, k elements are fixed, then $2^{n-k}$, not sure actually.

Comment: if I have n coinflips, and I can choose k of them to be heads...

Comment: @Zackkenyon It seems i got stuck at this point.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46555/discussion-between-zackkenyon-and-intainer).

Comment: @Zackkenyon My first assumption was definitely incorrect, because i thought i need at least k heads.